# How to efficiently query for all transactions involving a particular policy

Tags: cardano-node, cardano-db-sync

What is the best way (or perhaps only way) to query db-sync for transactions involving a specific policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention "policy" it means you are only interested in multi asset transactions which are all contained in the `ma_tx_out` table.

However, you need to be aware that multiple assets can have the same policy. If this is what you want, the query would be:

```
select ma_tx_out.* from ma_tx_out inner join multi_asset
  on ma_tx_out.ident = multi_asset.id
  where multi_asset.policy = '\x....' ;
```

If instead you want all transaction for the same multi-asset then the query would be:

```
select * from ma_tx_out.ident = ? ;
```

Comment: Thank you Erik! 
So ma_tx_out are the tx_out records for any policy and  multi_asset.id is the id of an asset that belongs to that policy?

Comment: Yes, all multi asset transactions are recorder in the `ma_tx_out` table. A `multi_asset.id` is actually a tuple of `(policy, name)` so that `(policy1, name1)` is different from `(policy1, name2)`. I suspect that you are actually interested in the `multi_asset.id` rather than the `policy`.

Comment: If you do `select * from multi_asset ;` you will see that each `multi_asset` row has a `fingerprint` which is probably what you should be using rather than `policy`.

Comment: If you do `select * from multi_asset order by policy limit 10 ;` you will see that there are rows with the same `policy` field, but since they have different `name` fields, their `fingerprint` fields also differ.

Comment: ...how can I use: 

where multi_asset.policy = '\x....' ;

...if the 'policy' column contains a byte array? Explicit conversion to a literal in the sql query itself? 
Thanks very much for all your responses Erik! I am learning!

Comment: ohh haha
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-binary.html